# How do I calculate a point estimate of the largest 10%?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, standard-deviation, means

Here is the provided data:

[image: Achieving a Target Value or Manufacturing Process]

The question asked is:
Calculate a point estimate of the value that separates the largest 10% of all values in the thickness distribution from the remaining 90% and state which estimator you used. [Hint: Express what you are trying to estimate in terms of μ and σ.]

The answer: 1.78138

How is the above 1.78138? I got that the σ = .3385 and μ = 1.348125, how do these values help me reach the answer? What must I do to further understand this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is you are trying to fit a normal distribution on your data. Your assumption is that the numbers you provided come from a normally distributed random variable, let's call it $X$.

You correctly calculated $\sigma$ and $\mu$, i.e., your assumption now is that $X$ is distributed as $N(\mu,\sigma)$. Now, the question is:

> What is the value $x_0$, such that $90\%$ of all values given by $X$ are **below** $x_0$?

Or, in other words,

> What is the value of $x_0$ such that the probability of a random sample from $X$ being below $x_0$ is $90\%$?

Comment: I don't really follow. So I'm being asked for a specific value x_0 such that x_0 is below the 90% of the sample from X? What does that mean?

Comment: @BrianPatino If $X$ is normally distributed, then $P(X<x) = ...$. Remember what should be on the right part of the equation?

Comment: @BrianPatino Also, try to read what I wrote exactly. I did not say "for a specific value $x_0$ such that $x_0$ is below $90\%$ of the sample". I **said** "the probability of a random sample from $X$ being below $x_0$".

Comment: I don't really remember... I do remember that for some distributions the integral of an equation would yield P(X < x). But I don't think the same applies here, unless I'm mistaken? I see that the normal density function is used [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats1/x21.pdf), would that help solve?

Comment: @BrianPatino Te integral and its connection to $P(X<x)$ is **precisely** what will help here. Since $P(X<x)$ is "the probability that $X$ is below $x$", and you need to calculate "$x_0$ such that the probability of $X$ being below $x_0$ is below $0.9$".

Comment: @BrianPatino Also, try to not "not remember" these things. If you want to do any serious statistics, knowing the probability distribution of normal variables is really your bread and butter. It's not something you learn and then forget, because forgeting it is like forgetting what $1+1$ is...